# Celery HPA - startupProbe failing after tasks are already running

Tags: python, kubernetes, celery, amazon-eks, hpa

I have Celery workers running on Kubernetes 1.20 cluster on AWS EKS using AWS Elasticache Redis as the broker. Because of the nature of the project ~80% of the time celery workers are running idle so the logical thing was to have them scale automatically. Scaling based on CPU/memory works ok. At about 4 workers node scaling also needs to kick in and that works ok as well.
An obvious problem is that it takes some time for a new node to start and get fully operational before that node can start taking on new celery worker pods. So some waiting to scale up is expected.

Somewhere in all that waiting a fresh celery worker pod gets started and starts accepting new tasks and executing them, but for some unknown reason the `startupProbe` does not complete. Because `startupProbe` was not successful the whole pod is killed potentially in the middle of a running task.

**Question**:
Can I prevent celery from taking on tasks before the `startupProbe` is considered successful?

Celery config

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: celery-worker
  labels:
    app: celery-worker
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: celery-worker
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 900
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: celery-worker
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: celery-worker
        image: -redacted-
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["./scripts/celery_worker_entrypoint_infra.sh"]
        env:
          - name: CELERY_BROKER_URL
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: celery-broker-url-secret
                key: broker-url
        startupProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "celery -q -A app inspect -d celery@$HOSTNAME --timeout 10 ping"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "celery -q -b $CELERY_BROKER_URL inspect -d celery@$HOSTNAME --timeout 10 ping"]
          periodSeconds: 120
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 3
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "celery -q -b $CELERY_BROKER_URL inspect -d celery@$HOSTNAME --timeout 10 ping"]
          periodSeconds: 120
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 5
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "384Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "500m"
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 2400
```

Celery HPA config

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
metadata:
  name: celery-worker
spec:
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 40
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: celery-worker
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 60
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 90
```

Celery startup script

```
python manage.py check
exec celery --quiet -A app worker \
        --loglevel info \
        --concurrency 1 \
        --uid=nobody \
        --gid=nogroup
```

I'm sharing complete configs including `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` whose values are a bit inflated, but are a consequence of various try-and-error scenarios.

**Edit:**
This is a catch-22 situation.

I have defined `startupProbe` to check if celery is running in current host and that will only be true if celery worker is running. And if celery worker is running it will accept tasks. And if it will accept tasks `celery inspect` command might take too long causing the `startupProbe` to hang and failing. If `startupProbe` fails too many times it will kill the pod.

Furthermore, if I call `celery inspect` without destination (host) defined, `startupProbe` will fail on initial deployment.

Conclusion: `celery inspect` is not a good `startupProbe` candidate.

Comment: Did you see [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes)? Do you have some logs from this killed pod?

Comment: Yup. My values for the `startupProbe` are actually from that doc. But I'm not sure that this is strictly a problem of a slow starting pod, but a problem where the `startupProbe` is failing (`celery inspect ping` command) but the startup command that start the main celery process got executed successfully and as such is accepting and processing tasks.


Log message is not very helpful: `"worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)"` :-/

Comment: I think I get it why the `startupProbe` fails: as I said before, celery tasks are already running and `celery inspect` command needs a fair amount of CPU which it does not have (task is using it) and so the probe dies before it manages to get successfully executed.

Comment: edited the original post with more info regarding celery-startupProbe combo

Comment: Is your application exposing some other health check (not connected to celery)?

Comment: It is. I have in another container a web service that uses Django framework and exposes health check at `/health`.

Comment: Did you try to set up startup probe based on your `/health` path?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that is a smart thing to do. If for instance my web service that serves `/health` gets DDoS-ed my celery workers would also fail.

Answer (score 1):

> Conclusion: `celery inspect` is not a good `startupProbe` candidate.

I agree.

You also mentioned that you have an active `healtcheck`

> I have in another container a web service that uses Django framework and exposes health check at `/health`

I think it is worth using it to create [startup probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes):

> Sometimes, you have to deal with legacy applications that might require an additional startup time on their first initialization. In such cases, it can be tricky to set up liveness probe parameters without compromising the fast response to deadlocks that motivated such a probe. The trick is to set up a startup probe with the same command, HTTP or TCP check, with a `failureThreshold * periodSeconds` long enough to cover the worse case startup time.

You also mention an example attack:

> Hmm, I'm not sure that is a smart thing to do. If for instance my web service that serves `/health` gets DDoS-ed my celery workers would also fail.

However, this shouldn't be a problem. Startup probe will only run when the container is started. The chance that someone will attack you while the environment is being launched is practically zero. You should use [readiness or liveness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes) probe to check if your container is alive while the application is running.

> The kubelet uses startup probes to know when a container application has started. If such a probe is configured, it disables liveness and readiness checks until it succeeds, making sure those probes don't interfere with the application startup. This can be used to adopt liveness checks on slow starting containers, avoiding them getting killed by the kubelet before they are up and running.

Here you can find example yaml

```yaml
ports:
- name: liveness-port
  containerPort: 8080
  hostPort: 8080

livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: liveness-port
  failureThreshold: 1
  periodSeconds: 10

startupProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: liveness-port
  failureThreshold: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
```

In this case `startupProbe` will execute on their first initialization, then will be used `livenessProbe`.

Comment: Using some other service as a health check just feels wrong to me. Maybe DDoS-ing is a bad example; general high usage where webserver pods still haven't managed to auto-scale up while receiving valid requests from users and where those valid requests are starting some celery tasks might be a better one. I'm trying something different, but still keeping it within the pod's scope. If I confirm that it's working, I'll post it here.

Comment: Is it not possible for you to issue an additional health check from the website you want to test?